# Spring Batch Repository: JdbcJobInstanceDao

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I have gone through the grepcode for `JdbcJobInstanceDao` and find out this code snippet which I am trying hard to understand.

According to the Spring Batch Repository Schema,

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT ,
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

JOB_NAME is actually Unique. But however in the `JdbcJobInstanceDao#getJobInstances(String jobName, int start,int count)` method, it is treated as if a list of entries can be existed in the BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE table for the same JOB_NAME.

Is this a possibility? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JOB_NAME` is not unique. The combination of `JOB_NAME`and `JOB_KEY` (which is a hash of the job parameters) is unique.

So multiple instances of the same job can exist, as long as they have different job parameters.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I didn't look at the SQL properly. My bad.